# Using compromised tor bridge

Tags: tor

If a malicious user creates a tor bridge, does that compromise the entire connection?

I don't think so, because I thought they have to control both the entry and exit nodes. However, my friend is saying that it does but I'm unsure why

Comment: Can you define what 'malicious' means in this case? And can you describe the process by which they might do that? Giving this detail should help folks understand the question better and give you more helpful answers. Good luck! (And welcome to the Security Stack Exchange!)

Comment: @securityOrange - They want to block me from using tor or read my traffic

Comment: How do you worry they would do that?